# SAP openui5: Error when attaching customData to a table column template

Tags: javascript, sapui5

When attempting to attach a custom data attribute to a table column using an XML view, I am receiving the following error in the Chrome browser console:

```
2016-02-12 12:02:38.331040 CustomData with key strikethrough should be written to HTML of Element sap.m.Text#__text10-col1-row6 but the value is not a string. -
```

My column definition is as follows:

```
<table:Column width="200px">
  <Label text="Plant Variation"/>
  <table:template>
       <Text text="{__textpvvalue__}">
            <customData>
                 <core:CustomData key="strikethrough" value="{__rowstyle__}" writeToDom="true" />
            </customData>
       </Text>
  </table:template>
</table:Column>
```

The attribute is actually correctly written out to the DOM, but it seems as if the error message should not occur as I am indeed passing a string value for the "value" attribute of the custom data object.  I also tried hard coding the "value" attribute of the custom data object to "test" thinking it might be a data binding related issue, but got the same result.

As the data attribute is actually being correctly written out to the DOM, this is more of an annoyance than a blocking issue.  I am wondering if this is a result of me not using custom data correctly in my XML view, as I am pretty new to openui5.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint here (https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/CustomData.js#L82) and see what is actually causing the problem? To see all source files, add `?sap-ui-debug=true` at the end of the URL path.

Comment: @Matt Hopkins: Your question about the problem with SAPUI5 Table control (Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined) is disappeared. Does it mean this problem is resolved? And, if yes, then how it is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use binding formatter. Format `null` value in some row to **empty string**.

```js
var customData = new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
    key: 'strikethrough',
    writeToDom: true
});
customData.bindProperty('value', {
    path: '__rowstyle__',
    formatter: function (value) {
        if (!value) {
            value = '';
        }
        return value;
    }
});
```

Or view formatter. See [Step 23: Custom Formatters](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.40.6/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html).

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    return {
        customDataFormatter: function (value) {
            if (!value) {
                value = '';
            }
            return value;
        }
    };
});
```